# Limiting Checkboxs that can be ticked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a form with several ingredients on it. I want a user to be able to select 3 and no more than 3. So if they ticked 3 then the form wouldn't allow any more but they could untick a choice and pick another.

At the moment though it doesn't stop a box from being ticked and doesn't count an untick.

My javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;
        function check() {
            if( $("input#name").checked = true )
                { 
                    total = total + 1;
                }
            if( $("input#name").checked = false )
                { 
                    total = total - 1;
                }
            if(total > 3)
                {
                    alert("Please Select only three")
                    $("input#name").checked = false ;
                    return false;
                }
        }
</script>
```

and my form

```
<form name="ingredientlist" method="post" action="checkboxdone.php">
        <label>Pork</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="pork" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Carrot</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="carrot" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Whiskey</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="whiksey" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Bacon</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="bacon" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Leek</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="leek" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Potato</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="potato" onclick="check();"/><br/>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="button"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug this into your code and it will run just dandy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var totalChecked = 0;
  $('form[name="ingredientlist"] > input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
      if (!this.checked) { //unchecking
          totalChecked--;
      } else if (totalChecked < 3) { //checking, with less than 3 checked
          totalChecked++;
      } else { //checking, with 3 checked
          this.checked = false;
      }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9gNg/1/

Comment: The comparison to false is hurting my eyes. `if (this.checked == false)` => `if (!this.checked)`

Comment: yeah, it does... i've answered questions where people have a hard time understanding when I use too much shorthand and the bangs seem to confuse those same people.. they just wanna see true or false.. i'll change it though :p

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you can count them up all at once and control them with just one little function:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
            this.checked = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Maybe somebody else is up to building a non-jQuery answer for you. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5pTV/) example.

Comment: ok so i put in that code and removed the onlcick event from the inputs, and no nothing happens at all. am i missing something ?

Comment: @RudigerKidd: You need to include the jQuery library for that sample to work. Sorry, I just assume everybody uses it :) (and you should).

Comment: i do, am using this one

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

First give ids to the checkboxes and hook onchange, not onclick

```
<form name="ingredientlist" method="post" action="checkboxdone.php">
        <label>Pork</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="pork" id="ckb_pork" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Carrot</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="carrot" id="ckb_carrot" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Whiskey</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="whiksey" id="ckb_whiksey" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Bacon</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="bacon" id="ckb_bacon" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Leek</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="leek" id="ckb_leek" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <label>Potato</label><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="potato" id="ckb_potato" onchange="check();"/><br/>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="button"/>
</form>
```

next do

```
//global scope
var ckb={pork: false, carrot: false, whiksey: false, bacon: false, leek: false, potato: false}

function check() {
  var checked=0;
  for (var ck in ckb) {
    //Cache DOM reference
    if (!ckb[ck]) ckb[ck]=document.getElementById('ckb_'+ck);
    if (ckb[ck].checked) checked++;
  }

  if (checked>=3) {
    for (var ck in ckb) {
      if (!ckb[ck].checked) ckb.disabled=true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: heya tried that, and got the error ckp is not defined. figured maybe it was a typo and tried ckb but then nothing happened. sorry.

Comment: Should have been ckb[ck] - fixed the answer and tested, please retry! Typo was a pasto

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle showing how you could accomplish it: http://jsfiddle.net/nCges/